# How to fix standard control property at desired value?

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, properties, controls

I want to have `TabControl.TabStop` property always set to `false`. I have made it read-only but designer seems to be adding it automatically into initializations what causes error

> Property 'TabStop' is ReadOnly

**In inherited control, how can I fix property value at constant value without these issues?** Should I just use empty setter instead of making the property read-only?

What I have:

```
public class SpecialTabControl : TabControl
{
    public bool TabStop {
        get { return false; }
    }

    public SpecialTabControl() : base()
    {
        base.TabStop = false;
    }
}
```

*(C# or VB, whatever you prefer.)*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do note the warning that your code produces, first thing you have to fix.  And yes, the TabControl designer completely expects the property to have a setter and will spit bullets when it doesn't.  So you have to provide a setter.

You'll also want to prevent the property from being visible in the Properties window and be explicit that the value must never be serialized.  Which all adds up to:

```
[Browsable(false)]
[DesignerSerializationVisibility(DesignerSerializationVisibility.Hidden)]
public new bool TabStop {
    get { return false; }
    set { base.TabStop = false; }
}
```

Give the TabIndex property the same treatment.

Comment: I greatly appreaciate the answer, even without checking .net books I feel in my guts this is standard approach for this stuff recommended across the framework, isn't it?

Comment: No, not at all, this is highly specific to Winforms.  Using the *new* keyword to suppress the compiler warning is normally pretty dangerous.  Not here.

Comment: For readers' benefit: in VB, you use `Shadows` instead of `New`.